# Add commas to large numbers in an ordered list in HTML

Tags: javascript, html, css, html-lists

Suppose you have an ordered list (`<ol>`) with thousands of items, eventually the numbers will have four digits, or even more.  These numbers would be easier to read if they were formatted as "1,234" instead of the browser default of "1234".  Is there any way to do this, with CSS, or JavaScript, or any other way?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's a pure CSS solution using [counters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Lists_and_Counters/Using_CSS_counters). Only tested in Chrome, and up to 2,001 items. Stackoverflow only lets me include 50,000 characters in my answer, so I trimmed down the snippet to 1,111 items.

If you expect your list to run into the millions, you would need to add additional counters and implement the corresponding CSS according to the pattern established below.

```css
ol {
  counter-reset: thousands;
  counter-reset: hundreds;
  counter-reset: tens;
  counter-reset: singles;
}
li {
  display: block;
}
li:nth-child(n) {
  counter-increment: singles;
}
li:nth-child(10n) {
  counter-reset: singles;
  counter-increment: tens;
}
li:nth-child(100n) {
  counter-reset: singles tens;
  counter-increment: hundreds;
}
li:nth-child(1000n) {
  counter-reset: singles tens hundreds;
  counter-increment: thousands;
}
li:before {
  content: counter(singles)". ";
}
li:nth-child(n+10):before {
  content: counter(tens) counter(singles)". ";
}
li:nth-child(n+100):before {
  content: counter(hundreds) counter(tens) counter(singles)". ";
}
li:nth-child(n+1000):before {
  content: counter(thousands)"," counter(hundreds) counter(tens) counter(singles)". ";
}
```

```html
<ol>
  <li>Item 1</li>
  <li>Item 2</li>
  <li>Item 3</li>
  <li>Item 4</li>
  <li>Item 5</li>
  <li>Item 6</li>
  <li>Item 7</li>
  <li>Item 8</li>
  <li>Item 9</li>
  <li>Item 10</li>
  <li>Item 11</li>
  <li>Item 12</li>
  <li>Item 13</li>
  <li>Item 14</li>
  <li>Item 15</li>
  <li>Item 16</li>
  <li>Item 17</li>
  <li>Item 18</li>
  <li>Item 19</li>
  <li>Item 20</li>
  <li>Item 21</li>
  <li>Item 22</li>
  <li>Item 23</li>
  <li>Item 24</li>
  <li>Item 25</li>
  <li>Item 26</li>
  <li>Item 27</li>
  <li>Item 28</li>
  <li>Item 29</li>
  <li>Item 30</li>
  <li>Item 31</li>
  <li>Item 32</li>
  <li>Item 33</li>
  <li>Item 34</li>
  <li>Item 35</li>
  <li>Item 36</li>
  <li>Item 37</li>
  <li>Item 38</li>
  <li>Item 39</li>
  <li>Item 40</li>
  <li>Item 41</li>
  <li>Item 42</li>
  <li>Item 43</li>
  <li>Item 44</li>
  <li>Item 45</li>
  <li>Item 46</li>
  <li>Item 47</li>
  <li>Item 48</li>
  <li>Item 49</li>
  <li>Item 50</li>
  <li>Item 51</li>
  <li>Item 52</li>
  <li>Item 53</li>
  <li>Item 54</li>
  <li>Item 55</li>
  <li>Item 56</li>
  <li>Item 57</li>
  <li>Item 58</li>
  <li>Item 59</li>
  <li>Item 60</li>
  <li>Item 61</li>
  <li>Item 62</li>
  <li>Item 63</li>
  <li>Item 64</li>
  <li>Item 65</li>
  <li>Item 66</li>
  <li>Item 67</li>
  <li>Item 68</li>
  <li>Item 69</li>
  <li>Item 70</li>
  <li>Item 71</li>
  <li>Item 72</li>
  <li>Item 73</li>
  <li>Item 74</li>
  <li>Item 75</li>
  <li>Item 76</li>
  <li>Item 77</li>
  <li>Item 78</li>
  <li>Item 79</li>
  <li>Item 80</li>
  <li>Item 81</li>
  <li>Item 82</li>
  <li>Item 83</li>
  <li>Item 84</li>
  <li>Item 85</li>
  <li>Item 86</li>
  <li>Item 87</li>
  <li>Item 88</li>
  <li>Item 89</li>
  <li>Item 90</li>
  <li>Item 91</li>
  <li>Item 92</li>
  <li>Item 93</li>
  <li>Item 94</li>
  <li>Item 95</li>
  <li>Item 96</li>
  <li>Item 97</li>
  <li>Item 98</li>
  <li>Item 99</li>
  <li>Item 100</li>
  <li>Item 101</li>
  <li>Item 102</li>
  <li>Item 103</li>
  <li>Item 104</li>
  <li>Item 105</li>
  <li>Item 106</li>
  <li>Item 107</li>
  <li>Item 108</li>
  <li>Item 109</li>
  <li>Item 110</li>
  <li>Item 111</li>
  <li>Item 112</li>
  <li>Item 113</li>
  <li>Item 114</li>
  <li>Item 115</li>
  <li>Item 116</li>
  <li>Item 117</li>
  <li>Item 118</li>
  <li>Item 119</li>
  <li>Item 120</li>
  <li>Item 121</li>
  <li>Item 122</li>
  <li>Item 123</li>
  <li>Item 124</li>
  <li>Item 125</li>
  <li>Item 126</li>
  <li>Item 127</li>
  <li>Item 128</li>
  <li>Item 129</li>
  <li>Item 130</li>
  <li>Item 131</li>
  <li>Item 132</li>
  <li>Item 133</li>
  <li>Item 134</li>
  <li>Item 135</li>
  <li>Item 136</li>
  <li>Item 137</li>
  <li>Item 138</li>
  <li>Item 139</li>
  <li>Item 140</li>
  <li>Item 141</li>
  <li>Item 142</li>
  <li>Item 143</li>
  <li>Item 144</li>
  <li>Item 145</li>
  <li>Item 146</li>
  <li>Item 147</li>
  <li>Item 148</li>
  <li>Item 149</li>
  <li>Item 150</li>
  <li>Item 151</li>
  <li>Item 152</li>
  <li>Item 153</li>
  <li>Item 154</li>
  <li>Item 155</li>
  <li>Item 156</li>
  <li>Item 157</li>
  <li>Item 158</li>
  <li>Item 159</li>
  <li>Item 160</li>
  <li>Item 161</li>
  <li>Item 162</li>
  <li>Item 163</li>
  <li>Item 164</li>
  <li>Item 165</li>
  <li>Item 166</li>
  <li>Item 167</li>
  <li>Item 168</li>
  <li>Item 169</li>
  <li>Item 170</li>
  <li>Item 171</li>
  <li>Item 172</li>
  <li>Item 173</li>
  <li>Item 174</li>
  <li>Item 175</li>
  <li>Item 176</li>
  <li>Item 177</li>
  <li>Item 178</li>
  <li>Item 179</li>
  <li>Item 180</li>
  <li>Item 181</li>
  <li>Item 182</li>
  <li>Item 183</li>
  <li>Item 184</li>
  <li>Item 185</li>
  <li>Item 186</li>
  <li>Item 187</li>
  <li>Item 188</li>
  <li>Item 189</li>
  <li>Item 190</li>
  <li>Item 191</li>
  <li>Item 192</li>
  <li>Item 193</li>
  <li>Item 194</li>
  <li>Item 195</li>
  <li>Item 196</li>
  <li>Item 197</li>
  <li>Item 198</li>
  <li>Item 199</li>
  <li>Item 200</li>
  <li>Item 201</li>
  <li>Item 202</li>
  <li>Item 203</li>
  <li>Item 204</li>
  <li>Item 205</li>
  <li>Item 206</li>
  <li>Item 207</li>
  <li>Item 208</li>
  <li>Item 209</li>
  <li>Item 210</li>
  <li>Item 211</li>
  <li>Item 212</li>
  <li>Item 213</li>
  <li>Item 214</li>
  <li>Item 215</li>
  <li>Item 216</li>
  <li>Item 217</li>
  <li>Item 218</li>
  <li>Item 219</li>
  <li>Item 220</li>
  <li>Item 221</li>
  <li>Item 222</li>
  <li>Item 223</li>
  <li>Item 224</li>
  <li>Item 225</li>
  <li>Item 226</li>
  <li>Item 227</li>
  <li>Item 228</li>
  <li>Item 229</li>
  <li>Item 230</li>
  <li>Item 231</li>
  <li>Item 232</li>
  <li>Item 233</li>
  <li>Item 234</li>
  <li>Item 235</li>
  <li>Item 236</li>
  <li>Item 237</li>
  <li>Item 238</li>
  <li>Item 239</li>
  <li>Item 240</li>
  <li>Item 241</li>
  <li>Item 242</li>
  <li>Item 243</li>
  <li>Item 244</li>
  <li>Item 245</li>
  <li>Item 246</li>
  <li>Item 247</li>
  <li>Item 248</li>
  <li>Item 249</li>
  <li>Item 250</li>
  <li>Item 251</li>
  <li>Item 252</li>
  <li>Item 253</li>
  <li>Item 254</li>
  <li>Item 255</li>
  <li>Item 256</li>
  <li>Item 257</li>
  <li>Item 258</li>
  <li>Item 259</li>
  <li>Item 260</li>
  <li>Item 261</li>
  <li>Item 262</li>
  <li>Item 263</li>
  <li>Item 264</li>
  <li>Item 265</li>
  <li>Item 266</li>
  <li>Item 267</li>
  <li>Item 268</li>
  <li>Item 269</li>
  <li>Item 270</li>
  <li>Item 271</li>
  <li>Item 272</li>
  <li>Item 273</li>
  <li>Item 274</li>
  <li>Item 275</li>
  <li>Item 276</li>
  <li>Item 277</li>
  <li>Item 278</li>
  <li>Item 279</li>
  <li>Item 280</li>
  <li>Item 281</li>
  <li>Item 282</li>
  <li>Item 283</li>
  <li>Item 284</li>
  <li>Item 285</li>
  <li>Item 286</li>
  <li>Item 287</li>
  <li>Item 288</li>
  <li>Item 289</li>
  <li>Item 290</li>
  <li>Item 291</li>
  <li>Item 292</li>
  <li>Item 293</li>
  <li>Item 294</li>
  <li>Item 295</li>
  <li>Item 296</li>
  <li>Item 297</li>
  <li>Item 298</li>
  <li>Item 299</li>
  <li>Item 300</li>
  <li>Item 301</li>
  <li>Item 302</li>
  <li>Item 303</li>
  <li>Item 304</li>
  <li>Item 305</li>
  <li>Item 306</li>
  <li>Item 307</li>
  <li>Item 308</li>
  <li>Item 309</li>
  <li>Item 310</li>
  <li>Item 311</li>
  <li>Item 312</li>
  <li>Item 313</li>
  <li>Item 314</li>
  <li>Item 315</li>
  <li>Item 316</li>
  <li>Item 317</li>
  <li>Item 318</li>
  <li>Item 319</li>
  <li>Item 320</li>
  <li>Item 321</li>
  <li>Item 322</li>
  <li>Item 323</li>
  <li>Item 324</li>
  <li>Item 325</li>
  <li>Item 326</li>
  <li>Item 327</li>
  <li>Item 328</li>
  <li>Item 329</li>
  <li>Item 330</li>
  <li>Item 331</li>
  <li>Item 332</li>
  <li>Item 333</li>
  <li>Item 334</li>
  <li>Item 335</li>
  <li>Item 336</li>
  <li>Item 337</li>
  <li>Item 338</li>
  <li>Item 339</li>
  <li>Item 340</li>
  <li>Item 341</li>
  <li>Item 342</li>
  <li>Item 343</li>
  <li>Item 344</li>
  <li>Item 345</li>
  <li>Item 346</li>
  <li>Item 347</li>
  <li>Item 348</li>
  <li>Item 349</li>
  <li>Item 350</li>
  <li>Item 351</li>
  <li>Item 352</li>
  <li>Item 353</li>
  <li>Item 354</li>
  <li>Item 355</li>
  <li>Item 356</li>
  <li>Item 357</li>
  <li>Item 358</li>
  <li>Item 359</li>
  <li>Item 360</li>
  <li>Item 361</li>
  <li>Item 362</li>
  <li>Item 363</li>
  <li>Item 364</li>
  <li>Item 365</li>
  <li>Item 366</li>
  <li>Item 367</li>
  <li>Item 368</li>
  <li>Item 369</li>
  <li>Item 370</li>
  <li>Item 371</li>
  <li>Item 372</li>
  <li>Item 373</li>
  <li>Item 374</li>
  <li>Item 375</li>
  <li>Item 376</li>
  <li>Item 377</li>
  <li>Item 378</li>
  <li>Item 379</li>
  <li>Item 380</li>
  <li>Item 381</li>
  <li>Item 382</li>
  <li>Item 383</li>
  <li>Item 384</li>
  <li>Item 385</li>
  <li>Item 386</li>
  <li>Item 387</li>
  <li>Item 388</li>
  <li>Item 389</li>
  <li>Item 390</li>
  <li>Item 391</li>
  <li>Item 392</li>
  <li>Item 393</li>
  <li>Item 394</li>
  <li>Item 395</li>
  <li>Item 396</li>
  <li>Item 397</li>
  <li>Item 398</li>
  <li>Item 399</li>
  <li>Item 400</li>
  <li>Item 401</li>
  <li>Item 402</li>
  <li>Item 403</li>
  <li>Item 404</li>
  <li>Item 405</li>
  <li>Item 406</li>
  <li>Item 407</li>
  <li>Item 408</li>
  <li>Item 409</li>
  <li>Item 410</li>
  <li>Item 411</li>
  <li>Item 412</li>
  <li>Item 413</li>
  <li>Item 414</li>
  <li>Item 415</li>
  <li>Item 416</li>
  <li>Item 417</li>
  <li>Item 418</li>
  <li>Item 419</li>
  <li>Item 420</li>
  <li>Item 421</li>
  <li>Item 422</li>
  <li>Item 423</li>
  <li>Item 424</li>
  <li>Item 425</li>
  <li>Item 426</li>
  <li>Item 427</li>
  <li>Item 428</li>
  <li>Item 429</li>
  <li>Item 430</li>
  <li>Item 431</li>
  <li>Item 432</li>
  <li>Item 433</li>
  <li>Item 434</li>
  <li>Item 435</li>
  <li>Item 436</li>
  <li>Item 437</li>
  <li>Item 438</li>
  <li>Item 439</li>
  <li>Item 440</li>
  <li>Item 441</li>
  <li>Item 442</li>
  <li>Item 443</li>
  <li>Item 444</li>
  <li>Item 445</li>
  <li>Item 446</li>
  <li>Item 447</li>
  <li>Item 448</li>
  <li>Item 449</li>
  <li>Item 450</li>
  <li>Item 451</li>
  <li>Item 452</li>
  <li>Item 453</li>
  <li>Item 454</li>
  <li>Item 455</li>
  <li>Item 456</li>
  <li>Item 457</li>
  <li>Item 458</li>
  <li>Item 459</li>
  <li>Item 460</li>
  <li>Item 461</li>
  <li>Item 462</li>
  <li>Item 463</li>
  <li>Item 464</li>
  <li>Item 465</li>
  <li>Item 466</li>
  <li>Item 467</li>
  <li>Item 468</li>
  <li>Item 469</li>
  <li>Item 470</li>
  <li>Item 471</li>
  <li>Item 472</li>
  <li>Item 473</li>
  <li>Item 474</li>
  <li>Item 475</li>
  <li>Item 476</li>
  <li>Item 477</li>
  <li>Item 478</li>
  <li>Item 479</li>
  <li>Item 480</li>
  <li>Item 481</li>
  <li>Item 482</li>
  <li>Item 483</li>
  <li>Item 484</li>
  <li>Item 485</li>
  <li>Item 486</li>
  <li>Item 487</li>
  <li>Item 488</li>
  <li>Item 489</li>
  <li>Item 490</li>
  <li>Item 491</li>
  <li>Item 492</li>
  <li>Item 493</li>
  <li>Item 494</li>
  <li>Item 495</li>
  <li>Item 496</li>
  <li>Item 497</li>
  <li>Item 498</li>
  <li>Item 499</li>
  <li>Item 500</li>
  <li>Item 501</li>
  <li>Item 502</li>
  <li>Item 503</li>
  <li>Item 504</li>
  <li>Item 505</li>
  <li>Item 506</li>
  <li>Item 507</li>
  <li>Item 508</li>
  <li>Item 509</li>
  <li>Item 510</li>
  <li>Item 511</li>
  <li>Item 512</li>
  <li>Item 513</li>
  <li>Item 514</li>
  <li>Item 515</li>
  <li>Item 516</li>
  <li>Item 517</li>
  <li>Item 518</li>
  <li>Item 519</li>
  <li>Item 520</li>
  <li>Item 521</li>
  <li>Item 522</li>
  <li>Item 523</li>
  <li>Item 524</li>
  <li>Item 525</li>
  <li>Item 526</li>
  <li>Item 527</li>
  <li>Item 528</li>
  <li>Item 529</li>
  <li>Item 530</li>
  <li>Item 531</li>
  <li>Item 532</li>
  <li>Item 533</li>
  <li>Item 534</li>
  <li>Item 535</li>
  <li>Item 536</li>
  <li>Item 537</li>
  <li>Item 538</li>
  <li>Item 539</li>
  <li>Item 540</li>
  <li>Item 541</li>
  <li>Item 542</li>
  <li>Item 543</li>
  <li>Item 544</li>
  <li>Item 545</li>
  <li>Item 546</li>
  <li>Item 547</li>
  <li>Item 548</li>
  <li>Item 549</li>
  <li>Item 550</li>
  <li>Item 551</li>
  <li>Item 552</li>
  <li>Item 553</li>
  <li>Item 554</li>
  <li>Item 555</li>
  <li>Item 556</li>
  <li>Item 557</li>
  <li>Item 558</li>
  <li>Item 559</li>
  <li>Item 560</li>
  <li>Item 561</li>
  <li>Item 562</li>
  <li>Item 563</li>
  <li>Item 564</li>
  <li>Item 565</li>
  <li>Item 566</li>
  <li>Item 567</li>
  <li>Item 568</li>
  <li>Item 569</li>
  <li>Item 570</li>
  <li>Item 571</li>
  <li>Item 572</li>
  <li>Item 573</li>
  <li>Item 574</li>
  <li>Item 575</li>
  <li>Item 576</li>
  <li>Item 577</li>
  <li>Item 578</li>
  <li>Item 579</li>
  <li>Item 580</li>
  <li>Item 581</li>
  <li>Item 582</li>
  <li>Item 583</li>
  <li>Item 584</li>
  <li>Item 585</li>
  <li>Item 586</li>
  <li>Item 587</li>
  <li>Item 588</li>
  <li>Item 589</li>
  <li>Item 590</li>
  <li>Item 591</li>
  <li>Item 592</li>
  <li>Item 593</li>
  <li>Item 594</li>
  <li>Item 595</li>
  <li>Item 596</li>
  <li>Item 597</li>
  <li>Item 598</li>
  <li>Item 599</li>
  <li>Item 600</li>
  <li>Item 601</li>
  <li>Item 602</li>
  <li>Item 603</li>
  <li>Item 604</li>
  <li>Item 605</li>
  <li>Item 606</li>
  <li>Item 607</li>
  <li>Item 608</li>
  <li>Item 609</li>
  <li>Item 610</li>
  <li>Item 611</li>
  <li>Item 612</li>
  <li>Item 613</li>
  <li>Item 614</li>
  <li>Item 615</li>
  <li>Item 616</li>
  <li>Item 617</li>
  <li>Item 618</li>
  <li>Item 619</li>
  <li>Item 620</li>
  <li>Item 621</li>
  <li>Item 622</li>
  <li>Item 623</li>
  <li>Item 624</li>
  <li>Item 625</li>
  <li>Item 626</li>
  <li>Item 627</li>
  <li>Item 628</li>
  <li>Item 629</li>
  <li>Item 630</li>
  <li>Item 631</li>
  <li>Item 632</li>
  <li>Item 633</li>
  <li>Item 634</li>
  <li>Item 635</li>
  <li>Item 636</li>
  <li>Item 637</li>
  <li>Item 638</li>
  <li>Item 639</li>
  <li>Item 640</li>
  <li>Item 641</li>
  <li>Item 642</li>
  <li>Item 643</li>
  <li>Item 644</li>
  <li>Item 645</li>
  <li>Item 646</li>
  <li>Item 647</li>
  <li>Item 648</li>
  <li>Item 649</li>
  <li>Item 650</li>
  <li>Item 651</li>
  <li>Item 652</li>
  <li>Item 653</li>
  <li>Item 654</li>
  <li>Item 655</li>
  <li>Item 656</li>
  <li>Item 657</li>
  <li>Item 658</li>
  <li>Item 659</li>
  <li>Item 660</li>
  <li>Item 661</li>
  <li>Item 662</li>
  <li>Item 663</li>
  <li>Item 664</li>
  <li>Item 665</li>
  <li>Item 666</li>
  <li>Item 667</li>
  <li>Item 668</li>
  <li>Item 669</li>
  <li>Item 670</li>
  <li>Item 671</li>
  <li>Item 672</li>
  <li>Item 673</li>
  <li>Item 674</li>
  <li>Item 675</li>
  <li>Item 676</li>
  <li>Item 677</li>
  <li>Item 678</li>
  <li>Item 679</li>
  <li>Item 680</li>
  <li>Item 681</li>
  <li>Item 682</li>
  <li>Item 683</li>
  <li>Item 684</li>
  <li>Item 685</li>
  <li>Item 686</li>
  <li>Item 687</li>
  <li>Item 688</li>
  <li>Item 689</li>
  <li>Item 690</li>
  <li>Item 691</li>
  <li>Item 692</li>
  <li>Item 693</li>
  <li>Item 694</li>
  <li>Item 695</li>
  <li>Item 696</li>
  <li>Item 697</li>
  <li>Item 698</li>
  <li>Item 699</li>
  <li>Item 700</li>
  <li>Item 701</li>
  <li>Item 702</li>
  <li>Item 703</li>
  <li>Item 704</li>
  <li>Item 705</li>
  <li>Item 706</li>
  <li>Item 707</li>
  <li>Item 708</li>
  <li>Item 709</li>
  <li>Item 710</li>
  <li>Item 711</li>
  <li>Item 712</li>
  <li>Item 713</li>
  <li>Item 714</li>
  <li>Item 715</li>
  <li>Item 716</li>
  <li>Item 717</li>
  <li>Item 718</li>
  <li>Item 719</li>
  <li>Item 720</li>
  <li>Item 721</li>
  <li>Item 722</li>
  <li>Item 723</li>
  <li>Item 724</li>
  <li>Item 725</li>
  <li>Item 726</li>
  <li>Item 727</li>
  <li>Item 728</li>
  <li>Item 729</li>
  <li>Item 730</li>
  <li>Item 731</li>
  <li>Item 732</li>
  <li>Item 733</li>
  <li>Item 734</li>
  <li>Item 735</li>
  <li>Item 736</li>
  <li>Item 737</li>
  <li>Item 738</li>
  <li>Item 739</li>
  <li>Item 740</li>
  <li>Item 741</li>
  <li>Item 742</li>
  <li>Item 743</li>
  <li>Item 744</li>
  <li>Item 745</li>
  <li>Item 746</li>
  <li>Item 747</li>
  <li>Item 748</li>
  <li>Item 749</li>
  <li>Item 750</li>
  <li>Item 751</li>
  <li>Item 752</li>
  <li>Item 753</li>
  <li>Item 754</li>
  <li>Item 755</li>
  <li>Item 756</li>
  <li>Item 757</li>
  <li>Item 758</li>
  <li>Item 759</li>
  <li>Item 760</li>
  <li>Item 761</li>
  <li>Item 762</li>
  <li>Item 763</li>
  <li>Item 764</li>
  <li>Item 765</li>
  <li>Item 766</li>
  <li>Item 767</li>
  <li>Item 768</li>
  <li>Item 769</li>
  <li>Item 770</li>
  <li>Item 771</li>
  <li>Item 772</li>
  <li>Item 773</li>
  <li>Item 774</li>
  <li>Item 775</li>
  <li>Item 776</li>
  <li>Item 777</li>
  <li>Item 778</li>
  <li>Item 779</li>
  <li>Item 780</li>
  <li>Item 781</li>
  <li>Item 782</li>
  <li>Item 783</li>
  <li>Item 784</li>
  <li>Item 785</li>
  <li>Item 786</li>
  <li>Item 787</li>
  <li>Item 788</li>
  <li>Item 789</li>
  <li>Item 790</li>
  <li>Item 791</li>
  <li>Item 792</li>
  <li>Item 793</li>
  <li>Item 794</li>
  <li>Item 795</li>
  <li>Item 796</li>
  <li>Item 797</li>
  <li>Item 798</li>
  <li>Item 799</li>
  <li>Item 800</li>
  <li>Item 801</li>
  <li>Item 802</li>
  <li>Item 803</li>
  <li>Item 804</li>
  <li>Item 805</li>
  <li>Item 806</li>
  <li>Item 807</li>
  <li>Item 808</li>
  <li>Item 809</li>
  <li>Item 810</li>
  <li>Item 811</li>
  <li>Item 812</li>
  <li>Item 813</li>
  <li>Item 814</li>
  <li>Item 815</li>
  <li>Item 816</li>
  <li>Item 817</li>
  <li>Item 818</li>
  <li>Item 819</li>
  <li>Item 820</li>
  <li>Item 821</li>
  <li>Item 822</li>
  <li>Item 823</li>
  <li>Item 824</li>
  <li>Item 825</li>
  <li>Item 826</li>
  <li>Item 827</li>
  <li>Item 828</li>
  <li>Item 829</li>
  <li>Item 830</li>
  <li>Item 831</li>
  <li>Item 832</li>
  <li>Item 833</li>
  <li>Item 834</li>
  <li>Item 835</li>
  <li>Item 836</li>
  <li>Item 837</li>
  <li>Item 838</li>
  <li>Item 839</li>
  <li>Item 840</li>
  <li>Item 841</li>
  <li>Item 842</li>
  <li>Item 843</li>
  <li>Item 844</li>
  <li>Item 845</li>
  <li>Item 846</li>
  <li>Item 847</li>
  <li>Item 848</li>
  <li>Item 849</li>
  <li>Item 850</li>
  <li>Item 851</li>
  <li>Item 852</li>
  <li>Item 853</li>
  <li>Item 854</li>
  <li>Item 855</li>
  <li>Item 856</li>
  <li>Item 857</li>
  <li>Item 858</li>
  <li>Item 859</li>
  <li>Item 860</li>
  <li>Item 861</li>
  <li>Item 862</li>
  <li>Item 863</li>
  <li>Item 864</li>
  <li>Item 865</li>
  <li>Item 866</li>
  <li>Item 867</li>
  <li>Item 868</li>
  <li>Item 869</li>
  <li>Item 870</li>
  <li>Item 871</li>
  <li>Item 872</li>
  <li>Item 873</li>
  <li>Item 874</li>
  <li>Item 875</li>
  <li>Item 876</li>
  <li>Item 877</li>
  <li>Item 878</li>
  <li>Item 879</li>
  <li>Item 880</li>
  <li>Item 881</li>
  <li>Item 882</li>
  <li>Item 883</li>
  <li>Item 884</li>
  <li>Item 885</li>
  <li>Item 886</li>
  <li>Item 887</li>
  <li>Item 888</li>
  <li>Item 889</li>
  <li>Item 890</li>
  <li>Item 891</li>
  <li>Item 892</li>
  <li>Item 893</li>
  <li>Item 894</li>
  <li>Item 895</li>
  <li>Item 896</li>
  <li>Item 897</li>
  <li>Item 898</li>
  <li>Item 899</li>
  <li>Item 900</li>
  <li>Item 901</li>
  <li>Item 902</li>
  <li>Item 903</li>
  <li>Item 904</li>
  <li>Item 905</li>
  <li>Item 906</li>
  <li>Item 907</li>
  <li>Item 908</li>
  <li>Item 909</li>
  <li>Item 910</li>
  <li>Item 911</li>
  <li>Item 912</li>
  <li>Item 913</li>
  <li>Item 914</li>
  <li>Item 915</li>
  <li>Item 916</li>
  <li>Item 917</li>
  <li>Item 918</li>
  <li>Item 919</li>
  <li>Item 920</li>
  <li>Item 921</li>
  <li>Item 922</li>
  <li>Item 923</li>
  <li>Item 924</li>
  <li>Item 925</li>
  <li>Item 926</li>
  <li>Item 927</li>
  <li>Item 928</li>
  <li>Item 929</li>
  <li>Item 930</li>
  <li>Item 931</li>
  <li>Item 932</li>
  <li>Item 933</li>
  <li>Item 934</li>
  <li>Item 935</li>
  <li>Item 936</li>
  <li>Item 937</li>
  <li>Item 938</li>
  <li>Item 939</li>
  <li>Item 940</li>
  <li>Item 941</li>
  <li>Item 942</li>
  <li>Item 943</li>
  <li>Item 944</li>
  <li>Item 945</li>
  <li>Item 946</li>
  <li>Item 947</li>
  <li>Item 948</li>
  <li>Item 949</li>
  <li>Item 950</li>
  <li>Item 951</li>
  <li>Item 952</li>
  <li>Item 953</li>
  <li>Item 954</li>
  <li>Item 955</li>
  <li>Item 956</li>
  <li>Item 957</li>
  <li>Item 958</li>
  <li>Item 959</li>
  <li>Item 960</li>
  <li>Item 961</li>
  <li>Item 962</li>
  <li>Item 963</li>
  <li>Item 964</li>
  <li>Item 965</li>
  <li>Item 966</li>
  <li>Item 967</li>
  <li>Item 968</li>
  <li>Item 969</li>
  <li>Item 970</li>
  <li>Item 971</li>
  <li>Item 972</li>
  <li>Item 973</li>
  <li>Item 974</li>
  <li>Item 975</li>
  <li>Item 976</li>
  <li>Item 977</li>
  <li>Item 978</li>
  <li>Item 979</li>
  <li>Item 980</li>
  <li>Item 981</li>
  <li>Item 982</li>
  <li>Item 983</li>
  <li>Item 984</li>
  <li>Item 985</li>
  <li>Item 986</li>
  <li>Item 987</li>
  <li>Item 988</li>
  <li>Item 989</li>
  <li>Item 990</li>
  <li>Item 991</li>
  <li>Item 992</li>
  <li>Item 993</li>
  <li>Item 994</li>
  <li>Item 995</li>
  <li>Item 996</li>
  <li>Item 997</li>
  <li>Item 998</li>
  <li>Item 999</li>
  <li>Item 1000</li>
  <li>Item 1001</li>
  <li>Item 1002</li>
  <li>Item 1003</li>
  <li>Item 1004</li>
  <li>Item 1005</li>
  <li>Item 1006</li>
  <li>Item 1007</li>
  <li>Item 1008</li>
  <li>Item 1009</li>
  <li>Item 1010</li>
  <li>Item 1011</li>
  <li>Item 1012</li>
  <li>Item 1013</li>
  <li>Item 1014</li>
  <li>Item 1015</li>
  <li>Item 1016</li>
  <li>Item 1017</li>
  <li>Item 1018</li>
  <li>Item 1019</li>
  <li>Item 1020</li>
  <li>Item 1021</li>
  <li>Item 1022</li>
  <li>Item 1023</li>
  <li>Item 1024</li>
  <li>Item 1025</li>
  <li>Item 1026</li>
  <li>Item 1027</li>
  <li>Item 1028</li>
  <li>Item 1029</li>
  <li>Item 1030</li>
  <li>Item 1031</li>
  <li>Item 1032</li>
  <li>Item 1033</li>
  <li>Item 1034</li>
  <li>Item 1035</li>
  <li>Item 1036</li>
  <li>Item 1037</li>
  <li>Item 1038</li>
  <li>Item 1039</li>
  <li>Item 1040</li>
  <li>Item 1041</li>
  <li>Item 1042</li>
  <li>Item 1043</li>
  <li>Item 1044</li>
  <li>Item 1045</li>
  <li>Item 1046</li>
  <li>Item 1047</li>
  <li>Item 1048</li>
  <li>Item 1049</li>
  <li>Item 1050</li>
  <li>Item 1051</li>
  <li>Item 1052</li>
  <li>Item 1053</li>
  <li>Item 1054</li>
  <li>Item 1055</li>
  <li>Item 1056</li>
  <li>Item 1057</li>
  <li>Item 1058</li>
  <li>Item 1059</li>
  <li>Item 1060</li>
  <li>Item 1061</li>
  <li>Item 1062</li>
  <li>Item 1063</li>
  <li>Item 1064</li>
  <li>Item 1065</li>
  <li>Item 1066</li>
  <li>Item 1067</li>
  <li>Item 1068</li>
  <li>Item 1069</li>
  <li>Item 1070</li>
  <li>Item 1071</li>
  <li>Item 1072</li>
  <li>Item 1073</li>
  <li>Item 1074</li>
  <li>Item 1075</li>
  <li>Item 1076</li>
  <li>Item 1077</li>
  <li>Item 1078</li>
  <li>Item 1079</li>
  <li>Item 1080</li>
  <li>Item 1081</li>
  <li>Item 1082</li>
  <li>Item 1083</li>
  <li>Item 1084</li>
  <li>Item 1085</li>
  <li>Item 1086</li>
  <li>Item 1087</li>
  <li>Item 1088</li>
  <li>Item 1089</li>
  <li>Item 1090</li>
  <li>Item 1091</li>
  <li>Item 1092</li>
  <li>Item 1093</li>
  <li>Item 1094</li>
  <li>Item 1095</li>
  <li>Item 1096</li>
  <li>Item 1097</li>
  <li>Item 1098</li>
  <li>Item 1099</li>
  <li>Item 1100</li>
  <li>Item 1101</li>
  <li>Item 1102</li>
  <li>Item 1103</li>
  <li>Item 1104</li>
  <li>Item 1105</li>
  <li>Item 1106</li>
  <li>Item 1107</li>
  <li>Item 1108</li>
  <li>Item 1109</li>
  <li>Item 1110</li>
  <li>Item 1111</li>
</ol>
```

Comment: Now that's what I call magic!  I wonder how hard this would be extend to handle 6 digit numbers.

Comment: Yeah, updated my answer for that. Basically you would just have to add two additional counters and implement them the same way as the existing ones.

Comment: Not seeing updated answer, but I guess I get the pattern

Comment: I didn't actually add the implementation because I think it would just make things less clear, so I just added a note after the first paragraph that you would need to add additional counters for very large lists.

Comment: Hm, can't this be optimized a bit?  We really only need two counters: one for the stuff before the comma, and one for the stuff after the comma.  The only issue I can think of is that it's not obvious how to prevent numbers like "1001" from displaying as "1,1" rather than the desired "1,001".  Hm...

Comment: That's indeed the issue, the formatting of numbers like 1,001

Comment: well, I guess at least there's no need for extra counters for six digit numbers: we can just keep using thousands

Comment: Yeah, you're right. Would have to start adding counters when you hit millions.

Answer (score 2):

To format your number or making it readable, You can use Intl.NumberFormat. Your browser should support ES6. If you're already using Babel that will do.

```
let x = 89000000;
console.log(Intl.NumberFormat().format(x));
```

Comment: But how do you apply this to format the automatically generated numbers from `<ol>` element list items?

Comment: Keep in mind that many modern browsers do NOT support ES6 including Safari and most mobile browsers.  As mentioned by OP, you will have to use an external tool such as Babel in order to make this cross-browser.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using the `<ol>` use loop through the elements, do a `list-style: none`, and display the index number and format that. You could use a regEx or use a library like momentJS to format the number.

Comment: Okay, so basically, do it by hand.  Fair enough.  Thanks.

Comment: [`Number#toLocaleString()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toLocaleString) will insert thousands separators by default, and it's cross-browser.

Comment: Yeah, but ick.  The page is already slow to load, thanks to having a list of several thousand elements.  Looping over all of them in JS would make that even worse.

Answer (score 1):

**Try this** [JsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/6f9want2/)

```js
//Javascript code (requires Jquery)

function format1(n, currency) {
  return currency + " " + n.toFixed(0).replace(/./g, function(c, i, a) {
    return i > 0 && c !== "." && (a.length - i) % 3 === 0 ? "," + c : c;
  });
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  $("li").each(function() {
  var k=format1(parseInt($(this).text()), "");
    $(this).text(k );
  });
});
```

```css
li {
  list-style: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ol id="formatThis">
  <li>1</li>
  <li>1234</li>
  <li>123423</li>
  <li>123422</li>
</ol>
```

**EDIT:**

1. if you want to decimal digits also just replace 0 in number of decimal places you want  `n.toFixed(0)`
2. if you want to show as currency eg:`$ 1,123` just pass the currency symbol in `format1(parseInt($(this).text()), "$");`

Answer (score 1):

You can use `String.prototype.match()` with `RegExp` `/\d/g` to match all digit characters; `Array.prototype.splice()` to insert comma character at array, `Array.prototype.join()` to return resulting string, `switch()` to replace digits. The implementation at stacksnippets inserts comma into string having up to ten digits `"1000000000"`

```js
function addCommaToNumber(num) {
  var n = String(num);
  var nums = n.match(/\d/g);
  var addComma = function(arr, index) {
    arr.splice(index, 0, ",");
    return arr.join("")
  }
  var res;
  switch (nums.length) {
    case 4:
      res = addComma(nums, 1);
      break;
    case 5:
      res = addComma(nums, 2);
      break;
    case 6:
      res = addComma(nums, 3);
      break;
    case 7:
      res = addComma(nums, 1);
      res = addComma(nums, 5);
      break;
    case 8:
      res = addComma(nums, 2);
      res = addComma(nums, 6);
      break;
    case 9:
      res = addComma(nums, 3);
      res = addComma(nums, 7);
      break;
    case 10:
      res = addComma(nums, 1);
      res = addComma(nums, 5);
      res = addComma(nums, 9);
      break;
    default:
      res = n;
  };
  return res
}

var ol = document.querySelector("ol");
var style = document.querySelector("style");

console.log(addCommaToNumber(1));

[10, "100", 1000, "10000", "100000"
, 1000000, "10000000", "100000000", 1000000000]
.forEach(function(num) {
  console.log(addCommaToNumber(num))
});

setTimeout(function() {
  console.clear();
  var keys = Array.from(Array(2001).keys());
  var i = 0;
  var raf = requestAnimationFrame(function addItem() {
    if (i < keys.length) {
      ol.innerHTML += `<li>${addCommaToNumber(i)}</li>`;
      // style.textContent += `li:nth-child(${i}):before{`
                               + `content:"${addCommaToNumber(i)} "`
                               + `}`;
      ++i;
      requestAnimationFrame(addItem)
    } else {
      cancelAnimationFrame(raf)
      
    }
  })
}, 1500);
```

```css
li {
  list-style:none;
}
```

```html
<ol></ol>
```